# Is it ok to say “I used to live in London for three years.”?

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to use “I used to live in London for three years.”? I feel a bit strange to use “I used to...” and “for...”.

Comment: You could try using a hyphen or comma before 'for'.

Comment: I would probably say 'I lived' rather than 'I used to live'.

Answer (score 2):

I think native speakers prefer to say *I lived in London for three years*

Non native speakers tend to use *used to* 
when simple past serves the purpose.

*I used to live in London for three years*

Both the sentences mean almost the same thing and talk about the completed actions in the past and also past habits.

I here with attach a link to show how used to can be used.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/used-to

Comment: Not quite - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72187/i-lived-vs-i-used-to-live/72205#72205

Comment: Different grammar books say differently

Comment: I used to live in London  for three years and I lived in London for  three years mean the same thing for even native speakers. We need not go very deep in to the matter when a learner wants to clarify their  question

Comment: Saying that they both mean the same allows the OP to use "*used to live*", which is very redundant and [it isn't very common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+to+live%2Clived&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20to%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clived%3B%2Cc0) in written English. I would suggest mentioning that the OP should use *"lived*" more frequently than "*used to live*".

Comment: *"I used to live in London for three years"* does not sound natural to me. It suggests the speaker would live in London for **three years at a time**. So 3 years in London, then somewhere else, then another 3 years in London and so on. Similarly, "I used to go to the gym for three hours".

Comment: I lived in London for three years. After that I lived in Bristol, where I told people 'I used to live in London, but now I live here'.

Comment: "I used to live in London. I was there for three years."