# What did you used to do?

Tags: questions, modal-verbs, used-to

Page 496 of Collins Cobuild English Usage reads

> You form 'yes/no'-questions with **used to** by putting *did* in front of the subject, followed by **use to**: *Did you **use to** do that, when you were a kid?*
>
> **WARNING**: many people use *used to* instead of *use to* in
> questions. However, some people consider that this use is incorrect,
>
> *Did you **used to** play with your trains?*
>
> If the 'wh'-word is the object of the clause, or part of the object, you
> use the auxiliary *do* after it, followed by the subject and *used to*,
>
> *What did you **used to** do on Sundays?*

I'd like to know why **use to** isn't  possible in the second structure, *What did you **use to** do on Sundays?*

**USED**: https://oed.com/oed2/00273881

Comment: As was pointed out several years ago by our resident linguist John Lawler, [***in writing, there is no standard accepted spelling of this expression***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153823/rhetorical-questions-with-used-to) *(Didn't it **use / used** to happen?)*. So the short answer is ***use to** IS possible in the second structure.* It's just that in the ***spoken*** version, no-one would normally know whether that ***/d/*** was present or not. Collins is being unwise in taking sides on this matter.

Comment: The reason why there isn't a standard is that both versions look wrong to experienced readers, for different reasons, and there's nothing that can be done about it. Except avoid it in writing, or get used to one of the variants (which one will be a problem, since everybody will decide on their own).

Comment: @JohnLawler why does this version look wrong? _What did you use to do on Sundays?_ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&corpus=26&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&content=what+did+you+use+to%2C+what+did+you+used+to&case_insensitive=on&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhat%20did%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhat%20did%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhat%20did%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwhat%20did%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhat%20did%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhat%20did%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @John: Haha - I like that *both versions look wrong to experienced readers!* I really wanted to be able to at least express a *preference* when writing my first comment here, but I find that when they're actually written down I don't like either. I have no problem at all with the spoken version (which to me can only have one form). It's a bit like exasperated / admonitory air sucked in between tip of tongue and palate - again, something I do all the time, but both ***Tut*** and ***Tsk*** look equally bad as *written* forms. And don't get me started on the "side click" for geeing up a horse!

Comment: It's not "use(d) to" but just "use(d)". The "to" is part of the VP functioning as complement of "use(d)". The correct forms are: In interrogatives, "Did you **use** to play ...?". In declaratives, "You **used** to play ...", and in negatives "You didn't use to play ...".

Comment: Yeah, but it **looks** wrong. Has nothing to do with grammatical function; it's vision and sound habits colliding with idiomatic lexical insertion.

Comment: The aspectual verb "use" has no present tense, no gerund-participle, and no past participle.  The plain form is found only in clauses with auxiliary "do",

Comment: The complication is that "use" can be either a lexical verb or an auxiliary. In "Used you to smoke?" it's an auxiliary, but in "Did you use to smoke?" it's a lexical verb by virtue of requiring _do_ support. Very few speakers treat it as an auxiliary.

Comment: @BillJ Page 496 of Collins Cobuild English Usage reads "You form 'yes/no'-questions with **used to** by putting _did_ in front of the subject, followed by _use to_: 

_Did you use to do that, when you were a kid?_"

Comment: @GJC  That's the _do_ support that I mentioned. The past tense form "used" only occurs in declaratives, as in "I used to smoke". Note that the verb is just "use(d)", not "use(d) to", except for those who take "use to" as an idiom, which I don't go along with..

Comment: @BillJ Still, why is **used** compulsory in wh-questions, unlike in yes/no-questions?

Comment: @GJC It's not, or at least it shouldn't be. The correct form is "What did you use to do when you were a kid?" where the plain form "use" is required following the dummy auxiliary "do", just as in any other VP (cf "Where did you go?", not *"Where did you went?"

Comment: @BillJ NGrams says differently https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+did+you+use+to%2CWhat+did+you+used+to%2CDid+you+use+to%2CDid+you+used+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20did%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20did%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CWhat%20did%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20did%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDid%20you%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @GJC The fact is that the dummy auxiliary "do" requires an infinitival complement except, as I've already explained, for those who take "used to" as an unchanging idiom.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00273881

Comment: I haven't heard anyone use "did + used to". It verily shows two-times use of 'did', like [did + (did use to) ]

Answer (score 2):

The normal, completely unremarkable negative (with *Do*-Support) of the idiom [*used to*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72205/15299) in

- *I used to like marshmallows.*
  /a'yustuˌlayk'marʃˌmɛloz/

is **pronounced** (note the **/st/** in both forms -- no /zd/ for *used* in this idiom)

- /aydɪdṇ'yustuˌlayk'marʃˌmɛloz/

and that's not a problem. In speech.

There isn't even much confusion with the almost identical idiom *be used to,*  meaning 'be accustomed to' -- most English speakers don't even notice that there are two of them.

But the past-tense-with-presupposition idiom *used to* does pose a problem, in writing. In speech it's treated as an infinitive, as required by *Do*-Support, no problem. But in writing *used* doesn't **look** like an infinitive; in fact, it's a past participle. But the idiom is spelled *used to*. Hence, there are two choices:

> a) *I didn't used to like marshmallows.*
>
> b) *I didn't use to like marshmallows.*

Both of these **look** wrong to experienced English readers, because
both of them contain sequences readers have been taught to avoid as products of grammatical mistakes:

- (a) contains ***didn't used***, which is wrong -- *Do*-Support doesn't make a participle *used*.
  So **that** looks wrong.
- (b) contains ***use to*** instead of *used to*, which is the idiom, so *use* gets  a /z/  .
  And **that** looks wrong, too.

Too bad, so sad, English orthography flunks again.

Comment: Page 496 of Collins Cobuild English Usage reads "You form 'yes/no'-questions with **used to** by putting _did_ in front of the subject, followed by _use to_: 

_Did you use to do that, when you were a kid?_"

Comment: Longman Pronunciation Dictionary: https://imgur.com/gallery/cObkvCM

Comment: One of the most spine-tingling things I've read. Nice!

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00273881

Answer (score -3):

There is a relevant account in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/used-to.

I dislike both constructions in written prose. To use "use" in the second may momentarily muddle the reader's understanding of "use" (="in past times") with the other sort of "use" (use on Sundays - to do what? Use of tools, for example).

I would always edit such questions to "Used you to play with your trains?"  and "What used you to do on Sundays?"

Comment: hast thou heard aught of the King's fate? Is he captured by Cromwell's men?

Comment: In "Used you to play ...", "use" is an auxiliary verb, but in "Did you use to play ...?" it's a lexical verb, as evident from the fact that it requires _do_ support. This is an important distinction.

Comment: What do they actually mean by _"Don’t use this form in written exams"_ ?

Comment: @GJC They probably mean that it may be used informally but that it is not suitable for educated writing.

Comment: @GJC: In other words, don’t use it when writing anything *that is going to be graded by an English teacher.*